# Как заменить часть сообщения в боте, написанном на Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Есть бот ретраслятор — он переотправляет сообщения целиком из одного канала в другой.
Нужно сделать так, либо чтобы сообщение отправлялось без последней строчки, либо чтобы можно было заменить последнюю строчку.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = '-------'

api_hash = '-------'
client = TelegramClient('--', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
@client.on(events.NewMessage(id канала 1))#ТЕСТ 1    
async def main(event):
     await client.send_message(id канала 2, event.message)
     
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно разделить `event.message` на строки, а затем удалить последнюю строку или заменить её, в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = '-------'

api_hash = '-------'
client = TelegramClient('--', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
@client.on(events.NewMessage(id канала 1))#ТЕСТ 1    
async def main(event):
     text = event.message.message.split('\n')  # разделяет сообщение на строки
     text = text[:-1]  # удаляет последнюю строку
     text[-1] = 'что-то другое'  # заменяет текст последней строки на что-то другое
     text = '\n'.join(text)

     await client.send_message(id канала 2, text)
     
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

---

Похоже, есть пробелы в понимании, как работают строки. Думаю, вам стоит поискать и почитать гайды по ним. Например, [вот этот](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html).

Comment: У меня огромные пробелы в понимании)
при использовании вашего кода выдает ошибку
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @user542404, спасибо, я обновил ответ. Попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 11 found Теперь это)
Думаю что задача пустяковая, но просто я не обладаю даже минимальными знаниями

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил ещё одну ошибку. Попробуйте снова)

Comment: Лучший, спасибо огромное!!!!!